# How do you supply a specific binary key to the PHP hash_hmac() function?

Tags: php, hmac

Assuming one has a **specific set of 128 bits** -- represented in hexadecimal as: `A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 55` -- how does one specify this value as the *key* to be used in the PHP 'hash_hmac' function?

That is, what will be the **actual value** typed in for the *'key'* argument?

```
hash_hmac('md5', 'The quick brown fox', '<what goes here for the above 128 bit value?>')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key can be whatever you want, and needs to be preserved for regeneration of the hash. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: No. I have a specific 128 bit key I want to use (as I've stated in the question). How do I enter _that_ key?

Comment: The *string* representation of the key or `A1B1C1D1E1F110203040506070809055`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hex2bin()` function will convert your hex string into a binary representation.  For example:

```
hash_hmac('md5', 'The quick brown fox', hex2bin('A1B1C1D1E1F110203040506070809055'))
```